# Jinja2 Ansible and map on nested yaml

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a yaml which looks like this :

```yaml
apache:
  apache_mods:
  - libapache2-mod-perl2
  - libapache2-reload-perl
  vhosts:
    - name: default
      servername: "*"
      port: 81
      conf-file: default.conf
      documentroot: /var/www/html
      directories:
        - path: "/var/www/"
          is_protected: "htpasswd1"
        - path: "/var/www/cgi-bin/" 
          is_cgi: "yes" 
        - path: "/var/www/html/data" 
          is_protected: "htpasswd3"
        - path: "/var/www/html/data-bandwith"
          is_protected: "htpasswd2"
        - path: "/var/www/html/fusion"
          options: |
            ForceType text/plain
        - path: /var/www/html/cedexis/
        - path: "/var/www/php"
          is_php: "yes"
          php_version: "5.6"
```

I want to get all `is_protected` values.

It's ok at the 2nd level : `"{{ apache.vhosts | map(attribute=\"port\") | list }}"` give me all ports for example but I can't access the 3nd level, chaining `map` isn't working at all.

Is there something I didn't understand ? Is a lookup mandatory for this kind of manipulation ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What does `{{ apache.vhosts | map(attribute=\"directories\") | list }} ` give you?

Comment: A debug task in ansible give me this:

ok: [test-ansible] => (item={u'name': u'default', u'directories': [{u'path': u'/var/www/', u'is_protected': u'htpasswd1'}, {u'is_cgi': u'yes', u'path': u'/var/www/cgi-bin/'}, {u'path': u'/var/www/html/data', u'is_protected': u'htpasswd3'}, {u'path': u'/var/www/html/data-bandwith', u'is_protected': u'htpasswd2'}, {u'path': u'/var/www/html/fusion', u'options': u'ForceType text/plain\n'}, {u'path': u'/var/www/html/cedexis/'}], u'port': 81, u'conf-file': u'default.conf', u'documentroot': u'/var/www/html', u'servername': u'*'})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch nested lists in chain:

```
- debug: msg="{{ apache.vhosts | map(attribute='directories') | sum(start=[]) | map(attribute='is_protected') | reject('undefined') | list }}"
```

I used `sum(start=[])` to flatten list of lists into single list.

Comment: The sum(start=[]) the thing i missed.
Thank you very much.
Alex.

Comment: I din't dig into history to get when it appeared exactly, but there is now a [`flatten` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-list-variables) available for that